# I am hearing buzzing, humming sound in silence. Is this problem with my ear or its progress in meditation?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, meditation-insight, meditation-effects, meditation

1. I was practice Breath Meditation then OM Chanting Meditation from year. and finally leave these both because its not suite for me.
2. Then I start Sound Meditation where I try to listen sound of my heart or other subtle sound. Last week I sit in meditation, after 2 minutes I hear sound like buzzing, hissing, humming.
3. from that day its continuously buzzing in my ear. Its

> Tinnitus

or

> Sound of Silence?

Comment: Hello Jyo and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have also a [*Help Center*](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) with a resource section for new users. Enjoy your time here.

Comment: [**Tinnitus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinnitus) would be evident regardless of the sound environment, though how noticeable it is depends on the severity of the condition and level of sound being heard compared to your usual environment. It can also vary between left and right ear. Depending on how much it interferes with daily activities, medical evaluation might be called for.

Comment: http://www.bahaistudies.net/asma/tinnitus.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing the same when I focus on hearing when there is no sound/noise (not an intense sound, but definitely a sense impression). Either both of us have bad ears or it's normal (it may be the sound of the blood floating in your brain or something). Nevertheless, if I don't keep my attention on it, it's not there.

I never did meditation on sound, but one option would be to chose another primary meditation object. There are enough of those. If you don't want to do breath meditation, you could use your body sensations as an object. There is a method called *[part by part sweeping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yN7zmBIS6ig)* (Link to a guided meditation by Ayya Khema), where you systematically notice sensations/feelings in your whole body. It has the advantage that you become more aware of emotions and reactions, since you are focused on all kinds of (changing) feelings and not i.e. only the breath going in and out. You can get quite concentrated with it, too.

If you want to stay with the sound as your object, you should notice the "hearing" and also your reaction to it ("worry", "dislike" ...).

Comment: Good and insightful answer.

Comment: I asked one of the Advance Meditation practitioner in India, He says its a sound of Universe. In Hindu its called "Bramaha Nada". He call me just let it go and Practice. Meaning of yoga is just let go. so I am now having faith that I am Progressing and I want to practice with patience...

Answer (score 0):

Buzzing humming sound can be that of breath energy. But if you practice according to the teachings of the Buddha, you will never face any problems.  The ‘Ehipassika’ Dhamma of the Supreme Buddha is open and transparent. So any issues that can arise can be openly discussed. An answer is always there in the scriptures.  For example... Abhibhayathana from Anguttara Nikaya 5 tells you how to overcome a type of obstacle a meditator faces in the form of colours – bright or subdued- of white, red, yellow, orange, blue, etc.

For a beginner, the maithri bhavana (loving kindness meditation) is the most important. It is not easy for everyone to properly do Anapanasati. So they have to first practice Asubha Bhavana and Dhathu/indriya Bhavana. You should not mix one meditation with another. You should get out of one type of meditation to get into another. Anytime when there is wandering thought, the concentration is not there. The appearing of a nimitta is a sign of concentration. When you develop an anapanasati nimitta, and practice it further, then you need a good knowledge of teachings (suttas) for you to overcome obstacles that you face.